# Код не компилируется на g++

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, операторы

Пытаюсь разобраться с тем, как перегрузить, напр., оператор вывода из `ostream` для нек. класса `class` и его наследника `inh` (в программе называются по-другому).

Препод наш в методичке пишет такую штуку:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, class& aclass)
{
  //какой-то вывод
  return stream;
}
```

и

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, inh& ainh)
{
  stream<<static_cast<class>(ainh);
  //какой-то вывод
  return stream;
}
```

Так вот, у меня возникла загвоздка со строчкой со `static_cast`. При попытке компиляции подобного кода компилятор выводит ошибку:

```
invalid initialization of non-const reference of type ‘class&’ from an rvalue of type ‘class’
stream<<static_cast<class>(ainh);
```

Путём гугления нашёл то, что в Visual Studio такой код работать будет, а в g++ - нет. А использовать майкрософтовские поделия - это не по мне.

Как сделать код рабочим на g++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я полагаю слово `class` вы неудачно выбрали для примера.:) Ключевые слова нельзя использовать для обозначения переменных.

Тем не менее.

Просто объявите второй параметр  как константную ссылку

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const class& aclass)
                                     ^^^^^
{
//какой-то вывод
return stream;
}
```

Желательно тоже самое сделать и во втором операторе

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& stream, const inh& ainh)
{
stream<<static_cast<class>(ainh);
//какой-то вывод
return stream;
}
```

Либо же вместо

```
static_cast<class>(ainh)
```

используйте

```
static_cast<class &>(ainh)
                 ^^^
```

Вот демонстрационная программа

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {};
struct B : A {};

std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream &os, A & )
{
    return os << "std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream &os, A & )" << std::endl;
}

std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream &os, B &b )
{
    return os << static_cast<A &>( b );
}



int main()
{
    B b;

    std::cout << b;

    return 0;
}
```

Ее вывод на консоль

```
std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream &os, A & )
```

Подытоживая, правильно было бы объявить операторы как

```
std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream &os, const A & )
                                             ^^^^^
{
    //...
}

std::ostream &operator <<( std::ostream &os, const B &b )
                                             ^^^^^
{
    return os << static_cast<const A &>( b );
                             ^^^^^^^^^
}
```

Проблема с вашим кодом сотсоит в том, что в этом выражении

```
static_cast<class>(ainh)
```

создается временный объект. А временные объекты могут быть привязаны лишь к константным lvalue ссылкам. А перегруженный оператор в базовом классе, который вы неудачно назвали ключевым словом class, в вашем примере имеет второй параметр как неконстантную ссылку.

Именно об этом говорит сообщение об ошибке

> invalid initialization of **non-const** reference of type ‘class&’ from an
>   **rvalue** of type ‘class’ stream<(ainh);

Если я не ошибаюсь, то если в свойствах проекта Visual Studio, отключить опцию "расширения языка", то код также не будет компилироваться. Но это вы можете проверить самостоятельно: действительно это так или нет.

Answer (score 3):

`class` это зарезервированное слово, оно не может быть использовано для имен типов. Возможно в методичке подразумевается что вместо "class" надо подставить имя своего класса.